# Is there a difference between 'a small smile' and 'a little smile'?

Tags: difference, adjectives

I was really angry but managed a small/little smile.

Is there any difference between a small smile and a little smile?

Comment: In your sentence *small smile* would be more appropriate.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31216/difference-between-little-and-small You can refer to this post too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two words in your example. As seen in the linked thread in the comments, when describing size, little/small are generally interchangeable. Since your example is describing the size of a smile, both are acceptable. I would argue that there is a difference in register, with 'little' being more informal than 'small'. I would never use 'little' in academic writing, for example. But since your example doesn't appear to be academic style, that is probably irrelevant.

If I may offer my personal preference, I feel that "little smile" sounds a bit more natural. However, I must stress that it is a completely stylistic choice.